# change my output format

Tags: php, sql

my php code is :

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT username FROM users LIMIT 3");
$users = array();
while($row = $db->fetchAll($q))
{
    $users[] = $row;
}


foreach($users as $user)
{


echo $user['username'].'<br>';

}
```

and the output will be

```
Nilsen
Michael
Sam
```

Does it possible to change my output format to be `Nilsen,Michael,Sam` without start foreach ?

Any idea please ?

Thank you.

Comment: replace the `<br>` with a comma in the echo statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($row = $db->fetchAll($q)) // fetchAll is wired here, but since you get the result, asume that's right
{
    $users[] = $row['username'];
}
```

then use:

```
echo join(',' $users);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and loop won't be needed on the php side.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(username) user_name FROM users LIMIT 3
```

- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: does it possible to give me an example for how my code should be, because i tried it but no success..thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT username FROM users LIMIT 3");
while($row = $db->fetchAll($q))
{
   print_r($row);
}
```

.

or

```
 echo $row[0], $row[1], $row[2];
```

I wouldn't recommend this for production though, just for checking/debuging..

Answer (score 0):

Mostly for debugging you can use like this :

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT username FROM users LIMIT 3");
while($row = $db->fetchAll($q))
{
    print_r($row); // or below
    var_dump($row);
}
```

The `var_dump()` function displays structured information about variables/expressions including its type and value. Arrays are explored recursively with values indented to show structure. It also shows which array values and object properties are references.

The `print_r()` displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans. array values will be presented in a format that shows keys and elements. Similar notation is used for objects.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT username FROM users LIMIT 3');

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$users = array_map(function($row) {
    return $row['username'];
}, $rows);

print_r($users);
```